# How to add http extension to HHVM

Tags: php, hhvm

I'm trying to use the HTTP extension with HHVM

As I can see here, its not supported yet:
https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Extensions

Is there any solutions like using pecl http extension or something?

Answer (score 0):

Since HHVM's extension API is different than PHP5's (and PHP7's for that matter), extensions have to be ported from PHP to HHVM. If this missing extension is important to you, you should [file an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues) -- I have no idea when we might be able to get to implementing it, but it will at least let us track it.

If you're interested in porting the extension yourself, there is [documentation on how to write HHVM extensions on our wiki](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Extension-API). We also have something called "ezc" which is designed to take *simple* PHP extensions and let them easily be recompiled for HHVM, but it only works on simple extensions, and I suspect this one doesn't qualify.